# GP Dynamics Report Writer Calculated Field RW_POPLINECommentText not showing on Blanket POs

Tags: report, microsoft-dynamics, writer, dynamics-gp

We need to have up to 12 comment lines show on line items on our purchase orders. I followed this GP Report Writer tutorial here: https://community.dynamics.com/gp/b/gpmarianogomez/posts/adding-more-comment-lines-to-pop-purchase-orders EXCEPT I could not figure out the suppress line comments: sSuppressComment1 = F6_LAST (C) Line 1 Comments = "" AND  F6_LAST (C) Line 2 Comments  = "".

I can find a field for "F6_LAST Line 1 Comments" but not "F6_LAST (C) Line 1 Comments" and modifying that throws an error.

Even without suppressing the comments, the new calculated fields appear on Standard POs, but no comments appear on Blanket POs. Blank lines do appear on the Blanket POs.

I would like to find out more about the fields that go into the expression (Line 1 Comments = FUNCTION_SCRIPT( RW_POPLINECommentText POP_PO.PO Type POP_PO.PO Number popPOLineRollupTemp.Ord 80 1 ), especially the "POP_PO.Po Type" field. I'm wondering if this could be my culprit. Is there a resource that goes through the Purchase Order Work Fields?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. The variable POP_PO.Po Type is an integer indicating the PO type:
PO Type:
1 – Standard
2 – Drop Ship
3 – Blanket
4 – Blanket Drop Ship

By replacing it with a hardcoded 1, the function now works on both Standard and Blanket POs. Using GP Dynamics 16. This could break on upgrades.

FUNCTION_SCRIPT( RW_POPLINECommentText 1 POP_PO.PO Number popPOLineRollupTemp.Ord 80 1 )